# $A^2+B^2 +AB=36. B^2+C^2+BC=49. C^2+A^2+AC=64.$ Find $(A+B+C)^2$

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry

> $$A^2+B^2 +AB=36.\\ B^2+C^2+BC=49.\\ C^2+A^2+AC=64.$$ Find $(A+B+C)^2$.

I have tried it by using geometry I.e constructing a triangle and marking a point inside it which is making 120 ° and then using cosine rule 
But have difficulty in solving further
Please use geometry

Comment: What's $A+B{}$?

Comment: What do you mean by "marking a point inside it which is making 120 °?"

Comment: @saulspatz Taking a triangle with sides $6,7,8$ and placing a point $P$ that looks at the sides at an angle of $120$ degrees. The distances from $P$ to the vertices of the triangle are $A,B,C$. The equation $\cos(120)=-1/2$, yields those three equations.

Comment: You can draw such a triangle and a point inside, such that the rays between the points make a $120^°$ angle between each other, then compute $(A+B+C)^2$, that will still not be a proof that this is the only possible value of the triplet $(A,B,C)$ and hence of $(A+B+C)^2$.

Comment: Eew! It looks like $(A+B+C)^2=\frac{82087461 + 29302035\sqrt{5} - 83076\sqrt{2355326 + 1045590\sqrt{5}} + 15211\sqrt{11776630 + 5227950\sqrt{5}}}{285076}$, when $A,B,C$ and positive.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier That is wrong. There are more solutions than the ones that can be lengths of segments.

Comment: If you tagged algebraic geometry then can we use Groebner basis? http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=groebner+%7Bx%5E2%2By%5E2%2Bxy+%3D+36,+y%5E2%2Bz%5E2%2Bzy+%3D+49,x%5E2%2Bz%5E2%2Bxz+%3D+64%7D

Comment: @LB_O  Your answer is identical to mine, quite magically.

Comment: @Batominovski It is because there is only one solution of the system in which $A,B,C>0$.

Comment: @AlexSilva To solve it using Groebner bases it should be done [like this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=groebner+%7Bx%5E2%2By%5E2%2Bxy+-36,+y%5E2%2Bz%5E2%2Bzy+-+49,x%5E2%2Bz%5E2%2Bxz+-+64,+(x%2By%2Bz)%5E2-w%7D) instead. The roots of the polynomial $w^2 - 149 w + 589$ in the basis, that is in $\mathbb{Q}[w]$ are all the possible values of $(A+B+C)^2$.

Comment: You can't calculate the answer with geometry, although you can construct a diagram in which a segment of length $A+B+C$ features. For example, see mengdie1982's answer or another five variants of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $A$, $B$, and $C$ are assumed to be positive real numbers, then consider a triangle $PQR$ with $p:=QR=7$, $q:=RP=8$, and $r:=PQ=6$.  Then, the (internal) angles of this triangle are all less than $\frac{2\pi}{3}$.  If $X$ is the [Fermat point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_point) of the triangle $PQR$, then $XP=A$, $XQ=B$, and $XR=C$.  Let $R'$ be a point on the opposite side of $QR$ with respect to $P$ such that $QRR'$ is an equilateral triangle.  Then, $A+B+C=PR'$.  This shows that
$$(A+B+C)^2=\left(PR'\right)^2=(PQ)^2+\left(QR'\right)^2-2\,(PQ)\,\left(QR'\right)\,\cos\left(\angle PQR'\right)\,,$$
where $PQ=6$, $QR'=QR=7$, and $\angle PQR'=\angle PQR+\frac{\pi}{3}$.  You are left to determine the values of $\cos(\angle PQR)$ and $\sin(\angle PQR)$, as
$$\cos\left(\angle PQR'\right)=\cos\left(\angle PQR+\frac{\pi}{3}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\,\cos(\angle PQR)-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\,\sin(\angle PQR)\,.$$

> The answer is $(A+B+C)^2=\frac{149+63\sqrt{5}}{2}$.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a purely algebraic way. Subtract the equations in pairs to get$$(C-B)(A+B+C)=28,$$$$(C-A)(A+B+C)=13,$$$$(A-B)(A+B+C)=15.$$Let us write $x=(A+B+C)^2$ and $y=BC+CA+AB$. Then squaring and adding the above three equations yields$$x(x-3y)=589.$$Summing the original equations gives$$2x-3y=149.$$Eliminating $3y$ between these equations results in the quadratic equation$$x^2-149x+589=0.$$Solving this, we get$$x=\tfrac12(149\pm63\surd5),$$where the larger root corresponds to the case when $A$, $B$, and $C$ are all positive.

Comment: John Bentin beat me to it. I'll just note the numerical values: (A, B, C) = (4.06836, 2.82240, 5.14819) or (1.00267, -6.43817, 7.45140); or of course the negatives of these.

Answer (score 4):

## Solution without words

Assume that $A,B,C>0.$
[image]